# WFS geometry or/and attributes issues

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

We have 4 people accessing shapefile data simultaneously in QGIS using a WFS from Geoserver.

We use a file as a container of shapefiles and we all have to work on the same shapefiles at the same time.

But we encounter some issues that we don't understand :

When we modify the geometry or the attributes of multiple entities in the shapefiles, if we don't save the shapefile between EVERY MODIFICATION, the attributes or the geometry is cloned and all the objects that we have modified have now the same geometry or the same attributes (the same as the last modified).

Can somebody explain why this is, and what we can do to fix it? Not sure if it is a bug or a misconfiguration.

Comment: GeoServer WFS and shapefiles may suit for experimenting but I would never ever use shapefiles when doing real work and your multi-user environment makes it even worse. Put your data into PostGIS as the first step.

Comment: Hello and thank you.
Ok so if I put my datas in a PostGIS DB we will be able to work in a mutli-users environment without data loss ?

Comment: Correct, that's the way to go.